# Remove 'tile' when clicked on

Tags: android

I'm working on a small project where you need to guess the picture behind the tiles. Currently everything is working, but I have no idea how I can check if someone clicked a tile.

I know I can do it with a button, but I want to be able to remove a tile when someone actually presses that tile. Is there a way to check if someone pressed somewhere on the screen or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your tile clickable, and then add a method on click event.

Add the following to your tiles in xml.

```
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="TileClicked"
```

Then create a method in your activity

```
public void TileClicked(View v)
{

     int clickedID = v.getId();

     // Do something to the clicked tile .. e.g.
     v.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);

     // or filter specific tiles
     if(clickedID = R.id.myTile1)
     {
         // do something when tile 1 clicked
     }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add the onclick listener in code and call the method there.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)